# Veracode throws Technology-Specific Input Validation Problems (CWE ID 100)

Tags: c#, veracode

**Error Heading** 
Technology-Specific Input Validation Problems (CWE ID 100)

**Error description:** 
Weaknesses in this category are caused by inadequately implemented input validation within particular technologies.

This error showing the error number where the constructor declared example below

```
public class BusinessRecipient : IModel
{
public List<string> ChProperties { get; set; }
public bool SldDisable { get; set; }

public BusinessRecipient()
{
ChProperties = new List<string>();
 }
}
```

I have tried the data annotation solution

```
public class BusinessRecipient : IModel
{
[Required]
public List<string> ChProperties { get; set; }
public bool SldDisable { get; set; }  

public BusinessRecipient()
{        
ChProperties = new List<string>();     
 }
}
```

Comment: Maybe both properties need the attribute?

Comment: It is throwing exception in BusinessRecipient() constructor line
public BusinessRecipient()
        {
            ChProperties = new List<string>();

        }

Comment: On SO you should never say something throws an exception without showing the exception details. However, maybe this is a Veracode issue that you can just ignore. Maybe if you put some validation in the `set`tter it will be happy though.

Comment: In error message i am getting the Error description as

 "Weaknesses in this category are caused by inadequately implemented input validation within particular technologies".